# Regards search view in android

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I implemented search view for filtering items in listview. It's working fine. My problem is search view showing > ( next icon ) in action bar. What is this? how can i remove this?

[image]

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)
                getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.
                getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        return true;
    }
```

search_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Try to clean/rebuild... Maybe, some id is pointing to wrong drawable

Comment: @GuilhermeP I was facing this from last few days.